# Array Data show not work

Tags: php, arrays

After querying my data from database I have this type of array in `$rown`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 60
    [id] => 60
    [1] => 78
    [cholest] => 78
    [2] => 2014-07-13
    [Cdate] => 2014-07-13
)

Array
(
    [0] => 61
    [id] => 61
    [1] => 0
    [cholest] => 0
    [2] => 2014-07-15
    [Cdate] => 2014-07-15
)
```

My code

```
$resultn = mysql_query($sqln);

if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
{
    while($rown = mysql_fetch_array($resultn))
    {
        $result_finalb = $rown["id"];
    }
}
```

when I print `$result_finalb` then show only second array data, but I want to show both array data.

Comment: Replace `$result_finalb=$rown["id"];` with `$result_finalb[] = $rown["id"];`

Answer (score 2):

You are setting a single variable `$result_finalb` with a value.
If you want to create an array of values, using `$result_finalb[]` will create an array item with the value you assign.
The first time will be `$result_finalb[0]`, second will be `$result_finalb[1]`, and so on through however many iterations you go through.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing square brackets. Use this:

```
$resultn = mysql_query($sqln);


if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
{
   while($rown = mysql_fetch_array($resultn))
   {
        $result_finalb[] = $rown["id"];
   }
}
```